# RHEL Java taking too long to start

Tags: java, redhat, rhel

I have installed RHEL 6.5 and am facing a performance issue with java.

```
# time java -version
java version "1.6.0_34"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.13.6) (rhel-1.13.6.1.el6_6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)

real    0m45.243s
user    0m0.149s
sys     0m0.086s
```

Comment: What are the machine specs? Internet connection speeds? Have you looked on the Red Hat site?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install version java version "1.8.0_31" and see if the numbers does improve. 
rpm -ivh jdk-8u31-linux-x64.rpm 
Also check the configuration page from RHEL. https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Communications_Platform/5.0/html/Platform_Installation_Guide/chap-Installing_and_Configuring_Java.html

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it was McAfee's nails process which was slowing down not only java but many other system processes. Stopping resolved the issue.